# gSOAP for WCF server with TCP binding and Callback events

Tags: c++, wcf, proxy

We need a C++ client application to consume WCF server with NetTCPBinding, and Callback events supported. I have generated the proxy using gSOAP 2.7.10. But my proxy does not communicate with server. When I use BasicHttp binding, it seems to work. Not sure of events.

Can anyone suggest me, if gSOAP works with TCP binding, and callback events.
I have already tried with Microsofts WWSAPI. It does not meet my requirements.
Is it worth trying gSOAP. If it does not work any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to the [NetTcpBinding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx)? From that page:

> The default configuration for the
>   NetTcpBinding is faster than the
>   configuration provided by the
>   WSHttpBinding, but it is intended only
>   for WCF-to-WCF communication.

So the answer is "no".

Comment: Yes, I was refereing to NetTcpBinding class. We have existing WCF server that exposes TCP endpoints. Now I have to consume these server in my C++ application. So i choose to generate proxy using gSOAP.

Answer (score 0):

As NetTcpBinding is only supported for WCF-WCF communication, you'll want to create a C# shim and expose this as a COM object for consumption by the C++ application.

Comment: I can't install .NET framework in my client site. So I have to develop a C++ application that interacts with WCF server.

Comment: Then you'll have to expose an additional endpoint on the WCF server, using something that works with gSOAP, like basicHttpBinding, maybe over SSL.